# Reading a complex csv file into a numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have such a csv file;

```
rgb-28.ppm
rgb-29.ppm (214.75142, 45.618622, 319.0, 152.53371, 0.91839749)
rgb-30.ppm (235.09999, 47.999729, 319.0, 147.49998, 0.88473213)  (281.05219, 54.649971, 319.0, 108.78567, 0.61637461)
```

On each line, there is the name of a file, and there is one or multiple tuples belonging to that file.

I want to read this csv file as the following.

On each row, the first column will involve the name of the file. The next columns will involve the tuples. If there won't be any tuple, the column will be empty. If there is a tuple, the tuple will occupy the column.

And when I want to read this file as the following;

```
contours = genfromtxt(path, delimiter=' ')
```

I get the following error:

> Line #36098 (got 6 columns instead of 1)

How can I read such kind of a file into a csv?

Thanks,

Comment: You might look at `pandas.read_csv`.  Pandas is better at dealing with missing data than `numpy`

Comment: since you know the the first column is the file name, you should use left parathensis as spliting  point and take is as a string that you split using ","

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a `csv`.  But it shouldn't be hard to read it line by line and parse them with regular python code.  Once you have lists of lists or tuples you can think about making arrays.

Comment: Do each of those tuples contain the same number of numbers, (5)?  Show us what you expect to get from the reader.  What you describe so far does not sound like array or table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The idea is, from the input file, find line which has the maximum number of columns. Use this, to construct a dynamic column list names. Pass this column list as the column names to Pandas. As mentioned in the comments, numpy is not efficient in handling the missing values. Once the data is in DataFrame, use the columns C1, C2, etc. to remove the unwanted characters, and then str.split to convert the numbers into a list to numbers.

```
import pandas as pd

l_max_col_nos = 0
l_f = open('data.csv','r')
for each_line in l_f:
    l_split = len(each_line.split('\t'))
    if l_split > l_max_col_nos:
        l_max_col_nos = l_split
l_f.close()
l_column_list = []
for each_i in xrange(l_max_col_nos):
    l_column_list.append('C' + str(each_i))
print l_column_list
l_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep='\t',header=None,names=l_column_list)
print l_df

print l_df['C1'].str.replace(')','').str.replace('(','').str.replace('\s','').str.split(',')
```

**Output**

```
['C0', 'C1', 'C2']
           C0                                                 C1  \
0  rgb-28.ppm                                                NaN
1  rgb-29.ppm  (214.75142, 45.618622, 319.0, 152.53371, 0.918...
2  rgb-30.ppm  (235.09999, 47.999729, 319.0, 147.49998, 0.884...

                                                  C2
0                                                NaN
1                                                NaN
2  (281.05219, 54.649971, 319.0, 108.78567, 0.616...
0                                                  NaN
1    [214.75142, 45.618622, 319.0, 152.53371, 0.918...
2    [235.09999, 47.999729, 319.0, 147.49998, 0.884...
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `genfromtxt(path, delimiter=' ')`, it reads each line, splits it on the delimiter.  Without further specifications it takes the number of split strings in the first line as the expected number for all lines.

The first line has just one string - so it expects one column all the way down.

The 2nd line has that string, but it also has those 5 number strings. Yes they are wrapped in `()` and separated by `,`; but they are also separated by the space.  `genfromtxt` does not handle `()`.

And then the 3rd line has 2 of those `()` blocks.

The `csv.reader` can handle quoted strings, but I don't think it can treat `()` as `"..."`.

Your parsing goal does not fit an array or table.  It sounds like you expect a variable of number of 'columns' per row, and that each such 'column' will contain this 5 number tuple.  That does not compute.  Yes, you could force that structure into an object type array, but the fit is bad.

However if each tuple of numbers contains 5, I can see creating a dictionary with the filename as key, and each tuple of that line as a row in a 5 column 2d array.  But regardless of target structure you need to figure out a way of one line, such as that one with 2 tuples.  How do split it on the spaces, without splitting on the ', '?  Once you have `()` groups you can strip off the `()`, and split on ', '.  The `re`, regular expression, module might be the best tool for this (I'll try to develop that).

=======================

A possible parsing of your example

Start with a line parsing function:

```
def foo(aline):
    alist = re.split(' \(',aline)
    key = alist[0]
    rest = alist[1:]
    rest = [r.strip().strip(')') for r in rest]
    if len(rest)>0:
       rest = np.array([[float(i) for i in r.split(',')] for r in rest])
    else:    
       rest = None
    return [key, rest]
```

Your sample text - copy-n-paste and split into lines

```
In [310]: txt="""rgb-28.ppm
rgb-29.ppm (214.75142, 45.618622, 319.0, 152.53371, 0.91839749)
rgb-30.ppm (235.09999, 47.999729, 319.0, 147.49998, 0.88473213)  (281.05219, 54.649971, 319.0, 108.78567, 0.61637461)"""

In [311]: txt=txt.splitlines()

In [312]: txt
Out[312]: 
['rgb-28.ppm',
 'rgb-29.ppm (214.75142, 45.618622, 319.0, 152.53371, 0.91839749)',
 'rgb-30.ppm (235.09999, 47.999729, 319.0, 147.49998, 0.88473213)  (281.05219, 54.649971, 319.0, 108.78567, 0.61637461)']
```

Now pass each line through the function:

```
In [313]: data = []    
In [314]: for line in txt:
   .....:     data.append(foo(line))

In [315]: data
Out[315]: 
[['rgb-28.ppm', None],
 ['rgb-29.ppm',
  array([[ 214.75142   ,   45.618622  ,  319.        ,  152.53371   ,
             0.91839749]])],
 ['rgb-30.ppm',
  array([[ 235.09999   ,   47.999729  ,  319.        ,  147.49998   ,
             0.88473213],
         [ 281.05219   ,   54.649971  ,  319.        ,  108.78567   ,
             0.61637461]])]]

In [316]: data[2][1].shape
Out[316]: (2, 5)
```

The last line contains the data in a 2x5 array.  The first has `None`.

Splitting on ' (' seems to be enough to handle the larger groups.  It leaves a trailing ')' on the groups, but that's easy to strip off.  The rest is to split each group into substrings, and convert those to floats.

As written the function has no error checking or robustness, but it is a start.  The data might not exactly in the form you want, but it can be reworked as needed.